# app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my 'build.gradle'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ksmk.sahip.com.masjid"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
   compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
   implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
   implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
   implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
}
```

I've checked most of the SO answers for this issue, but nothing worked for me.

I've already tried the following:

**1. clean and rebuild the project.**

**2. MultidexEnable is already true.**

**3. Invalidate cache and restart the Android studio.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be solve your problem

> android:largeHeap="true"

add this in manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_rounded"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: `<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`                                                                   Not Working